# Install wine for RED HAT enterprise linux 6

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux, avi, wine

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Install wine on RHEL with Yum](https://superuser.com/questions/231565/install-wine-on-rhel-with-yum)

I just can't install wine on red hat enterprise linux 6. When i download the binary package it had so many dependencies that i prefered to ask the experts for assistance and their guidance. Can somebody guide me in installing this..I just want to run Photoshop and few other windows based programs.
Here i also take the opportunity to ask about playing of avi files in Linux.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://superuser.com/questions/231565/install-wine-on-rhel-with-yum

Comment: Create a new question to ask about the AVI files - or just do a google for it - there's many resources out there.